# Inconsistent routing in Go fasthttp with fasthttp/router

Tags: go, routes, fasthttp

I am working on a Go server that uses FastHTTP with `github.com/fasthttp/router` routing package. But I have been experiencing routing inconsistencies with it. I tried every fork of the `fasthttp/router` package and I am having problems with every single one. Here is the problem:

I have my **main.go** file here:

```golang
package main

import ...

func main() {
  // ...
  go routes.RegisterHealthRoutes(router)
  go routes.RegisterUserRoutes(router)
  go routes.RegisterPostRoutes(router)

  log.Fatal(fasthttp.ListenAndServe(addr, middleware.CORS(router.Handler)))
}
```

Now, in my routes package (I am only showing one of them but the other implementations are the same), I am registering controllers on specific endpoints based on the function.

Here is one of them (`func RegisterPostRoutes()`) 
**routes/posts.go**

```golang
package routes

import (
    post_controllers "tea-share/controllers/posts"

    "github.com/fasthttp/router"
)

func RegisterPostRoutes(router *router.Router) {
  go router.GET("/posts", post_controllers.GetPosts)
  go router.GET("/posts/search", post_controllers.GetPostsBySearchTerm)
  go router.POST("/posts", post_controllers.CreatePost)
  go router.PATCH("/posts/{id}/like", post_controllers.LikePost)
}
```

Here is my go build command:

```bash
$ go build -tags netgo -ldflags "-extldflags '-static' -s -w" -o bin/tea-share
```

This registers the routes successfully, sometimes... 
Many times, one route registers, while many don't. In my testing environment, I ran the server, it registered all of the `/posts`, but when it came to `/users`, it missed two routes, (`/users/login` and `/users/signup`)

Then when I closed the server and started it again, it registered all users routes, but it failed to register `/posts/{id}/like` and `POST /posts`. I closed and ran it again, then it registered both `/users` and `/posts` correctly but failed to register `/health` (My health check route so my hosting provider thought my server had failed health check)

And remember, when I mean "failed to register", it can mean many things. What I am experiencing is either:

- The endpoint returns 404 (Not Found)
- The endpoint returns 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Another error that may seem weird but *it does happen* many times, that when I start the app, it panics and gives me this error:

```bash
fatal error: concurrent map writes

goroutine 39 [running]:
github.com/fasthttp/router.(*Router).Handle(0xc000126b60, {0xddd865, 0x3}, {0xde559d, 0xd}, 0xe35cf8)
        /home/dev-siri/Desktop/Projects/Go/pkg/mod/github.com/fasthttp/router@v1.4.19/router.go:231 +0xa5
github.com/fasthttp/router.(*Router).GET(0x0?, {0xde559d?, 0xbd5f46?}, 0xc000126b60?)
        /home/dev-siri/Desktop/Projects/Go/pkg/mod/github.com/fasthttp/router@v1.4.19/router.go:117 +0x33
created by tea-share/routes.RegisterUserRoutes
        /home/dev-siri/Desktop/Projects/JavaScript+Dart/Tea-Share/apps/server/routes/users.go:11 +0xad
```

Although, when I do nothing and start the app again, it starts up successfully, and then instead of the app crashing, it just has route registration errors like I mentioned above.

What is going on with `fasthttp/router`? Removing the `go` keyword before the `router.[METHOD]` calls also do nothing, things for some reason just break harder sometimes.
I am unable to ship the app because of this unreliable routing mechanism. Is it something to do with the router or my code? Can someone please help?

Comment: @JimB I ran the detector. First it gave me a lot of conditions that it couldn't even fit in my terminal. I removed all the `go` calls before `route.[METHOD]` and between `routes.Register` calls, then it started up properly. Looks like running them as go routines was the problem.

Comment: Yes, those calls are not safe for concurrency, nor does it even make sense to have routes registered later after the sever has possibly started. Don’t throw the `go` keyword in everywhere expecting some magical improvements

Comment: Yea, the concurrency was so simple that I went over board with it.